# PHP Codeigniter with Apache on alpine linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter, alpine-linux

i have written a small codeigniter test app that is currently running on my windows box.
i created a linux vm and have tried to install the app on this new virtual server. 
some of my web app is running properly but other parts, no. 
specifically, this works:

```
 http://123.123.123.123/myapp/controller1/
```

but this does not:

```
 http://123.123.123.123/myapp/controller2/mymethod/1/2/3
```

It fails with an error that it can't load controller2_model.

Here's the actual code for the controller that is failing (it's really called xferLogger vs. controller2):

```
 class xferLogger extends CI_Controller { 
      public function __construct() { 
              parent::__construct();
              echo(2); 
              $this->load->model('xferLogger_model'); 
              $this->load->helper('date'); //this library is needed for the base_url() method that is being called in the view "result.php" 
              $this->load->helper('url'); 
      }
```

and here's the model:

```
class xferLogger_model extends CI_Model { 
    public function __construct() { 
              $this->load->database();
                }
```

The full error message is: An error was encountered.  Unable to locate the model you have specified:  xferlogger_model.

Here's something I noticed. in the error message, you'll notice that the "L" in logger is lowercase.  but in my code, it's a capital L. 
I've checked in my controller, the model itself, and also the routes.php file.  I can't seem to find any problems with my casing.

??

Comment: Showing the full error would be helpful.

Comment: Also are you sure you copied everything including hidden files like .htaccess

Comment: Linux is case sensitive, maybe this is messing up your app.

Comment: as *SérgioMichels* already mentioned, on linux (and, IIRC, any other non-windows system) both file/directory names and mysql table names are case sensitive. And also , "does not work" is not a valid error message.

Comment: the full error message is: "An error was encountered.  Unable to locate the model you have specified:  mycontroller2_model".  I have copied everything over... I checked for discrepancies with the case.. haven't noticed anything so far.  will keep checking.

Comment: also confirmed the the constructor for the controller is being called but it dies right when i try to load my model...

Comment: can you please post your code where you try and load the model? Can you please also post your model (just the first bit + constructor). But I agree with people above - you probably have "Controller2_model.php" - it should be "controller2_model.php"

Comment: class xferLogger extends CI_Controller {
 
       public function __construct()
       {
              parent::__construct();
              echo(2);
              $this->load->model('xferLogger_model');
              $this->load->helper('date');
              //this library is needed for the base_url() method that is being called in the view "result.php"
              $this->load->helper('url');
       }  
and here's the model: 
<?php
    class xferLogger_model extends CI_Model{
             public function __construct()
              {
                $this->load->database();}

Comment: i've checked folders, table names, file names.  other models in the same folder are being loaded without any problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the userguide: Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. So therefore:

```
class Xferlogger_model extends CI_Model // First letter capitalised
```

and your model load

```
$this->load->model('xferlogger_model');  // lower case
```

and your PHP filename

```
xferlogger_model.php    // lower case
```

[Codeigniter Model Userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Comment: that did not resolve my problem.  i went through controller, model and routes and replaced xferLogger with Xferlogger everywhere.

Comment: I've improved my answer. Can you please also re-edit your original quesiton with the updated code(s) and error(s) that this gives?

Comment: ok.  so your latest suggestion to change the model name to all lowercase did make a difference.  it now works.  so the take away lesson is then to keep all model names lowercase?

Comment: and my apologies for not reading the manual carefully.  this is not an excuse.. but i'm trying to move from windows, wamp, mysql to linux, postgres, apache.  and codeigniter, linux, and postgres are all new to me so i'm kinda drowning in docs.  thanks for the help.